# how to store a appended list into a .txt file in python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a list which is a list of appended items

```
if words[0] == "[" or words[len(words)-1] == "]":
            if words in combinations1:
                line.append(words)
```

when i try to put this list into a single file i am able to get only the last item in the list.

my code to write this into a file is :

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as output_file:
                    output_file.write(str(line))
```

I need to write all the list items into the file. How to do it

Comment: Do you want to store each list entry in a new line?

Comment: yes I need to store each entry into a new line in the file

Comment: BTW, `words[len(words)-1]` is the same as `words[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for word in line:
        output_file.write(word)
```

it will put all words in a line of the file if you want them in different lines:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for word in line:
        output_file.write(word + '\n')
```

and if you want them in one line with a space between them:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write(line.join(' '))
```

Comment: Doesn't work! It gives an output - if the list is ['that', 'is', 'the', 'end', '.']

then the output is something like "thatistheend." this in the file

Comment: what is your desired output with that list?

Comment: consider these are the items in the list after appending `['uh', '[/]', 'not', 'gonna', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'that', 'rabbit', '.']
['that', 'guy', 'c', '[//]', 'that', 'w', '[/]', 'that', 'rabbit', 'want', 'a', 'balloon', '.']
['and', 'he', 'is>', '[/]', 'he', 'is', 'going', 'get', '[/]', 'get', 'some', 'money', 'and', 'get', 'a', 'balloon', '!']
['he', '[/]', 'he', 'get', '[/]', 'he', 'hold', 'it', '.']
['that', 'is', 'the', 'end', '.']`

I need to store these entire items that is in the list named line into a .txt file

Comment: man. it is 5 list, not one. you want them exactly like this in that file ?

Comment: Please explain me how does a list look like after appending? does it get stored in a same list named line or does it get stored as 5 different list? and yes i need them exactly like this in a file

Comment: what I'm saying is the content of `line` variable cant be this. it is 5 different lists.is it list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
open("neededfile.txt","w").write("\n".join([str(content) for content in sendable]))
```

This code snippet does it in one line, basically you join the various entries.
Using the str() works if your item is not of string datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write(" ".join(words))
```

Also, in the if statement you don't need to call `len`, simply index your list with `-1` to get the last element of the list like so: `if words[0] == "[" or words[-1] == "]"`.